# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar elementos duplicados de un array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en JavaScript y me he encontrado con un problema en el que necesito eliminar elementos duplicados de un array. He buscado en la documentación de JavaScript y he encontrado algunos métodos como filter(), reduce(), y Set, pero no estoy seguro de cuál es la mejor forma de abordar este problema.

He intentado algunas soluciones, pero ninguna parece funcionar correctamente en mi caso específico. Aquí está parte de mi ***código*** para que puedan entender mejor el contexto:

```js
// Mi array con elementos duplicados
const arreglo = [0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7];
```

¿Alguien puede proporcionar una solución efectiva para eliminar elementos duplicados de un array en JavaScript? Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega lo que has intentado para solucionar el problema. ;)

Comment: Es una tarea bastante sencilla, de la cual hay muuuucha información y ejemplos en internet... Claramente no estás mostrando que es lo que has intentado, agrégalo!. Probablemente tengas algún error sencillo de sintaxis en alguna de tus tantas opciones que has revisado

Comment: ¿Mejor en qué sentido? ¿Menos código? ¿Más eficiente en tiempo o memoria?

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer de muchas maneras, una fácil es usando [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const arreglo = [0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7];

const arregloUnico = Array.from(new Set(arreglo));

console.log(arregloUnico);
```

Edit: gracias @Yussef por el comentario.

Comment: Gracias! Me habia olvidado del `Array.from()`